# Best solution for my task: Thread, AsyncTask or Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-moxy

I have an Android application that creates and edits requisitions.  All the data is going to be stored at my server.

A problem is: the app should regulary get information from the server on existence of some records by generating queries. Time interval between queries towards server should be about 30 seconds.

1) Could you please advise, what is the best way to solve this problem? Maybe there is any better option I've missed?

At the moment I am considering the following options to choose:

- Thread
- AsyncTask
- Service

2) For Service, should I use it at the main thread or place it into another?

3) Also, as far as I know, Thread or AsyncTask are recreated with Activity, when user rotates a phone. Maybe I can use [Moxy library](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/tree/master/sample-github) with AsyncTask instead of worrying about Activity recreation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you know how to deploy websocket and use it,i recommend you to deploy a websocket and connect your android app to it, it's my idea ...

Comment: if you want to get information from sever regulary  then there are only one way is Service !!

Comment: web socket check continue sly means regularly ?? not requirement of service ?

Comment: i think his purpose of service was android service

Comment: So do you want to call the server in every 30 seconds?

Comment: with websocket you wait for message to receive, when new message received then you process it, no timer needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need task run in background then Service is best option than `AsyncTask` and if you want to run your task every 30 seconds then you can use Alarm Manager is good for interval task, but Alarm Manager will consumes a lot of battery.

There is another best solution for Scheduled task That is **JobSchedular**.

**AlarmManager**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/6676466

**JobSchedular** // I Suggest it

[Complete Job Scheduler Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49527268/6676466)

I suggest you read and use **JobSchedular**

Comment: It's look like JobSchedular is really not intended for such short intervals. From API 26 (Oreo), setting a smaller period than 15 minutes for periodic jobs will execute at least after 15 minutes. Until Android 5.1.1 - atleast after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Service,it can keep running indefinitely in background. and you canals spawn a thread from service.